# RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered - Resnet18 on PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to use PyTorch's Resnet18 model with my image data. Given the complexity of the model as well as the size of the data, I'd like to run it using CUDA. I'm doing the follow:

```
resnet_cnn = models.resnet18(pretrained = True)
num_ftrs = resnet_cnn.fc.in_features
resnet_cnn.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 8)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().cuda()
optimizer_ft = optim.SGD(resnet_cnn.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
exp_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer_ft, step_size=5, gamma=0.1)
```

After this, I attempt to train and test my model with the following loop:

```
count = 0
loss_list = []
iteration_list = []
accuracy_list = []
epochs = 30

for epoch in range(epochs):
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(trainloader):
            resnet_cnn = resnet_cnn.cuda()
            images.cuda()
            labels.cuda()

            optimizer_ft.zero_grad()
            outputs = resnet_cnn(images.cuda())
            loss = criterion(outputs.cuda(), labels.cuda())
            loss.backward()
            optimizer_ft.step()

            count += 1

            if count % 50 == 0:
                correct = 0
                total = 0

                for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(testloader):
                    # images.to(device)
                    # labels.to(device)

                    outputs = resnet_cnn(images.cuda())
                    predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)[1]
                    total += len(labels)
                    correct += (predicted == labels.cuda()).sum()
                accuracy = 100 * correct / float(total)

                loss_list.append(loss.data)
                iteration_list.append(count)
                accuracy_list.append(accuracy)

                if count % 500 == 0:
                    print("Iteration: {} Loss: {} Accuracy: {} %".format(count, loss.data, accuracy))
```

But I am met with the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-cb669e8d47c0> in <module>()
      7 for epoch in range(epochs):
      8     for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(trainloader):
----> 9             resnet_cnn = resnet_cnn.cuda()
     10             images.cuda()
     11             labels.cuda()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in cuda(self, device)
    489             Module: self
    490         """
--> 491         return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
    492 
    493     def xpu(self: T, device: Optional[Union[int, device]] = None) -> T:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _apply(self, fn)
    385     def _apply(self, fn):
    386         for module in self.children():
--> 387             module._apply(fn)
    388 
    389         def compute_should_use_set_data(tensor, tensor_applied):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _apply(self, fn)
    407                 # `with torch.no_grad():`
    408                 with torch.no_grad():
--> 409                     param_applied = fn(param)
    410                 should_use_set_data = compute_should_use_set_data(param, param_applied)
    411                 if should_use_set_data:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in <lambda>(t)
    489             Module: self
    490         """
--> 491         return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
    492 
    493     def xpu(self: T, device: Optional[Union[int, device]] = None) -> T:

RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
```

I can't figure what I'm doing wrong as I've trained a manually defined CNN in the same way. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you try to run the code in the CPU? Usually the output is way more self-explainable when the code has been run in the CPU rather than the GPU

Comment: The problem is in the other lines, you have to set everything to cpu to make the stacktrace work properly

Comment: hello @FrancescoAlongi, @ NatthaphonHongcharoen - if I run the model on CPU is works fine, but processes very slowly through the loop. If I run on the CPU then I will not get an error. Have I misunderstood you?

Comment: plz check what this line returns `torch.cuda.is_available()`

Comment: Hello @PrajotKuvalekar - ```torch.cuda.is_available()``` returns ```True```

Comment: u have multi gpu?

Comment: @PrajotKuvalekar I am using the GPU on Google Colab Pro

Comment: try using 1 gpu

Comment: @PrajotKuvalekar could you elaborate please, I'm not sure I follow you

Comment: Normally colab uses multiple gpu device...so try setting single gpu